# REST console guide

Tags: rest, console, google-chrome-devtools

I am using REST console; and i don't know how to fill the RAW body of "Request Payload"?

This is part of "Form Data" that i got by chrome developer tool - Network- headers:

```
criteria:{"boardMember":{"value":"Include","isUsed":true},"workHistory":{"value":"CurrentAndPast","isUsed":true},"includePartialProfiles":{"value":true,"isUsed":true},"lastUpdated":{"value":0,"isUsed":true},"personName":{"value":"tayson","isUsed":true}}
```

I should note that the "Request header" and "response header" does match.
any help?

Answer (score 0):

can you please open a ticket at https://github.com/codeinchaos/restconsole/issues?state=open